# After cloning WP and deleting all posts and pages, some previous domain links are found by Google

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress

Through the clone function in Softaculous, I cloned a WP installation to a brand new domain. First thing, I deleted all posts, pages, media, etc. then I created a few new pages, generated a sitemap with All in One SEO, checked it, and submitted it to Google Webmaster Tools. To my surprise, there are 3 crawl errors, pointing to pages of the old site.

I looked everywhere but I can't understand where Google got those links! Where can they hide?

Comment: You need to check Webmaster Tools and click 'LINKED FROM' then delete those references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be better ways to do this but when stuck, my default tool is [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

Download all site files, download the database, then use ST to do a find (or find and replace) for the old domain (and/or IP address). Be careful though, WordPress uses serialized strings.